# How can i put the title of the meme and the upvotes and the link to the meme in the embed discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meme(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

so that is my meme command rn i need help to put the title and amount of upvotes in the embed

Comment: FYI, `pass_context` isn't needed in the recent versions of discord.py. [See Migration Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#context-changes)

Comment: What have you tried/attempted?

Answer (score 0):

You can set those attributes via

```
embed.title = "<your-title>"
embed.url = "https://<your-url>"
```

And for the upvotes you could add a field

```
embed.add_field(name = "Upvotes", value = "<your upvotes>")
```